# Maximum Power Point Tracker (MPPT) charge controller - what drives the weight?

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, charger, solar-charge-controller, mppt

I'm having trouble finding any literature paper that studies this problem. What drives the weight of an MPPT charge controller? How would I go about reducing that weight if I had to design a custom design? The only thing that even alludes to the power-to-weight of an MPPT is this paper, behind a firewall so I can't read it: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7990724

The clue here is that it's the power transistors that are massive? If I had to design an MPPT with an expected range of input/output voltages and currents, how could I go about determining the heavier objects? Maybe this schematic was potentially the most helpful thing I found, which details the inside of an MPPT: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiduej8a/tiduej8a.pdf?ts=1593845160703&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

But there's no mention of weight of anything. Of course, I could buy an OTS MPPT and strip off the housing, etc. to reduce mass, but I'm trying to go for a more sophisticated design approach. I guess weight has never mattered to MPPTs, being installed near large solar panels on houses, etc., but it is an interesting problem (I think?). What are the components by weight? How can they be reduced (e.g. GaN power transistors apparently?)? And what's the driving factors (e.g. is it current that pushes the need for heavier everything?)

Apologies if this is basic electronics - I am new to the electronics world.

Comment: You can minimise the mass of the unit by designing for one battery voltage, eliminating the display etc but then it becomes targeted to a particular use and not so sellable.

Comment: MPPT charge controller includes tiny PCB's that can charge on 12V battery at 1 or 2 Amps, and it also includes giant inverter/charger/controllers that can charge a 10kWh battery bank or even bigger. But in general, I think thermal components such as heat-sinks will end up being the heaviest. Current probably is the single biggest driver toward larger heatsinks.

Comment: One approach, if component cost is not a major constraint, would be to use very low resistance switching elements (possibly MOSFET's) and try to get very high efficiency. If you can achieve 99% efficiency with 1000W you only have to dump 10 Watts. But if it is 95% efficient you need to dump 50 Watts. So you can maniacally pursue high efficiency at every point. Forced air cooling will probably be a win for weight, but not necessarily for reliability. If some other type of cooling is available due to the particular use case for this unit, maybe you can use that. Liquid cooling for example.

Comment: Another approach is to increase the switching frequency. MPPT charge controllers are (usually) basically buck converters, which store energy in an inductor when the switch is ON, and release it when OFF. The size (and weight) of the inductor depends on the energy storage needed, so cycling it faster reduces the energy per cycle and thus the inductor size. But switching faster implies more switching losses, and more heat, and bigger heatsinks, so ... balance this with mkeith's efficiency drive.

Comment: @SolarMike definitely not for commercial, so anything that helps the physics could be adopted independent of market potential. Why does designing for one battery voltage help? Does the size of the DC convertor inside change based on output voltage?

Comment: @mkeith In this example (https://www.enfsolar.com/pv/charge-controller-datasheet/3420?utm_source=ENF&utm_medium=charge_controller_list&utm_campaign=enquiry_product_directory&utm_content=110589) they rate the nominal battery voltage. Doesn't this mean they designed for a specific battery and not the range you talked about? Or is this typically the highest rating possible?

Comment: If you reduce the required output voltage (battery voltage) range, higher efficiency should be possible because you are only optimizing for one voltage. Same for input voltage. If the charger does not need to support a wide range of step-down ratios it can be made more efficient. Step-down is Vin/Vout. The heatsink needs to be designed to accommodate the least efficient point in the operating window. If you restrict the window, then you can use a smaller heatsink.

Comment: I don't know if you have scope to alter the system design. But in general, since lower current is a bit better, it can be advantageous to use higher voltage batteries. Also, it is advantageous if the solar panel voltage is a bit higher than the fully charged battery voltage. So you can use a simple buck converter and not a buck-boost or what have you. So you want the expected actual MPPT voltage of the array to be higher than the maximum required battery voltage. Rated MPPT is usually specified at 25C, but that may not be realistic for panels in full sunlight... So study the output curves.

Comment: @mkeith Thanks. As of now, the system voltage is not selected, but the MPPT may not be the driving force behind its selection anyway. Pardon my ignorance, but i don't really understand the why behind: "higher efficiency should be possible because you are only optimizing for one voltage". I understand the resulting thermal condition being more beneficial, but electrically, what determines that higher efficiency for a narrow voltage vs a larger one? Maybe I need to read up on DC-DC convertors...

Comment: USUALLY buck converters are most efficient when Vout is close to Vin. This is because the duty cycle is highest, and ripple current is lowest. In a buck converter with a large step-down ratio, the inductor will actually be a transformer. This means the duty cycle can be 100 percent when Vin/Vout = k, where k is some constant number. If both Vout and Vin are highly constrained, k can be chosen so that the duty cycle is close to 100% all the time, and thus more efficient.

Comment: Are you launching something into space? MPPTs are normally designed for 24/7 (not that 24 in real life of course) and stationary application so no need to save weight but rather maximize efficiency and minimize cost. If you can live with slightly lower efficiency and a tailored solution for your particular case, you can push the magnetics down in size and weight.

Comment: @winny not space, but near-space. Unfortunately that also means efficiency is super important so we want to have the highest efficiency possible. But since our voltage in/out ranges are known, we could design an efficient MPPT for our design point, based on some of the comments above. Additionally, our expected heat dissipation at that point will be known, so we can size the heat sinks/fans accurately instead of oversizing like a lot of commercial MPPTs. We can also use cooling from the environment the MPPT is in which could further reduce it's size

Comment: Sounds like a very fun project! If it’s a one off or very low volume, you can always spend more money on semiconductors than economical for stationary applications and “cheat” that way. I’d go for an all SiC or GaAs solution if I where you and select the panels MPPT voltage to match your desired bus voltage to be a ratio to that of an integer divided by integer (there is a word for it?) and match your number of phases in your buck converter accordingly.

Comment: You need to tell us what the REAL problem is - we can guess but may be somewhat off. Is this PV panel to load or battery to load or .... . Why is therer a range of voltages? What is the power level and Vin and Vout and variations in all those. If you want to minimise power converter mass then knowing the true task is crucial. As is the environment. Rather than hinting at "near space" can you tell us the time/environment profile? | You may not think all of this is essential - but you don't know and you may well be wrong. We are happy to 'get our teeth' into substantial problems BUT ...

Comment: ... we do need to know what they are. Vast amounts of time can be wasted delta incrementing the problem spec and going down blind allies. || If you DO need MPPT (PV panels about the only likely reason) then you MAY have a buck converter (but we don't know battery spec V I W mass chemistry - of if you run mainly batteryless. It's just possible that a radical solution such as total loss phase change cooling and minimal heatsinks makes sense BUT, again, we need to know the true problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a strict or definitive way to define it here, so the measurement goal should be the capabilities of the controller, if you want a more powerful mppt controller you want better components, they may be thicker and bigger. So the weight will increase accordingly.

Comment: Comment only: That's not an overly useful answer. Have a look through the comments where there is quite a lot of good material. And note this is a spacelike environment. He has not given us a marvellous spec, yet, but there will be specific answers when/if he does so.